# does exist some software to edit the audio signal before it "arrives" to the speakers?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, jack, audio-recording

i need some software to cut all the audio signal from my pc above a certain frequence, do you know anything that would work?
i'd like to use some audio server like pulse or jack but i can't find the option (if it exists) in both of the software!

Comment: did you tried pulseaudio equalizer ?